# Finding method's class in Magento

Tags: methods

I've installed AdFab Avatar extension. It has 2 methods that interest me: `getAvatarValid` and `setAvatar`.

`setAvatar` is called on `$_avatar` in some .phtml files and `getAvatarValid` called via `$customer->getAvatarValid()` in `Observer.php`.

I wanted to check the source of these methods so I did `grep -r "n setAvatar`(for both functions) on the whole Magento folder. I didn't get any result. How come? Are they saved in the database :)?

Comment: http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.ro/2010/05/how-to-find-methods-in-magento.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely that `setAvatar()` is just calling a magic method to add a value into the data array of whatever object `$_avatar` is.  The call to `getAvatarValid()` is probably also using a magic method to pull a value assigned to the `$customer` object in some other code.

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) for a little information on PHP magic methods.

Comment: Thanks Marius and Jonathan! I have read somwhere about magic methods before but completely forgot about it.

Answer (score 0):

May be where you are finding that method is not available on your searching folders.

May be they are overloading customer and you will find the method over there
"$customer"->getAvatarValid().

Find  with grep -r "function getAvatarValid()" /root/magento/
you will get your method.
Thank you